Stop shift+space from creating unbreakable space, make it create a normal space instead
I want to remap Shift+Space to type a normal space because I often accidentally hit Shift+Space while coding, thus typing an unbreakable space, which causes annoying errors. I am using Swaywm. How could I remap Shift+Space?


Use Autokey or alternative, https://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/?platform=linux, to steal key-press and change to space. 2. Ignore issue and do global search/replace at end of day.

